# Format string into Time from datatable C#

Tags: c#, datetime, time, datatable

I am creating a datatable from excel import and bulkcopying it to database, I need to put the `Scheduled Start as start time` into database as time hh:mm:ss but it keeps going into database as 30/12/1899 10:30:00, all I want is the 10:30:00 to go into database.  How can I do this?

I have tried converting to DateTime and then formating but keeps saying it is not a valid DateTime.

```
                using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + sheet1 + "]", excel_con))
            {
                oda.Fill(dtExcelData);

            }
            excel_con.Close();


            if (dtExcelData.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow rw in dtExcelData.Rows)
                {
                    //Creates StaffID
                     rw["StaffID"] = "00" + rw["Host Key of Staff"].ToString();

                    //Creates Start Time
                     rw["Scheduled Start as start time"] = rw["Scheduled Start as start time"].ToString("hh-mm");

                }
               // Response.Write(strConcate);
            }
```

Comment: Use the right datatype, so datetime instead of string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have a DateTime without both a date and a time. If you try to omit the time, it'll probably default to midnight. If you omit the date, it apparently defaults to Dec 30, 1899 in the database.

If you don't see a column type for only Time, you'll have to either:

- use a string or text type for that column and store the time as a string like you're currently attempting to do, or
- keep the column as a Date/Time and don't worry about the date portion that's stored

I'd do it the second way, and then use a format string like `.ToString("hh-mm")` so that the user only sees the portion you want them to see. They'll never realize you've stored a date. This way, you're not storing the time as a string and then needing to manipulate it back into the correct format later on when you inevitably try to do some calculation with it.

Comment: So I set database column type to DateTime and change string to DateTime as well?

Comment: Ok So I have put the date in as DateTime and it is storing as `1899-12-30 01:00:00.000`  I only want to show the user in a gridview 01:00 how do I do this?  Do I create sql statement and select the data from database but what do I do to get each result and format the Scheduled Start as Start time.  Sorry for being a pain

Comment: Nope not using WinForms :s should i?

Comment: I am using asp.net with c# and a normal gridview.

Comment: Do you have any idea how I would get just the hh:mm from the Scheduled Start as Start time in c# and store as integer?

Comment: I have another column called TotalHoursTaught which has the data 1899-12-30 01:30:00 stored, when I show it to users it will be displayed as 01:30 which means 1 hour 30 minutes which is find but I want to change this is 1.50 which means 1 and hour hours, I know I have to * 01:30 by 24 so get this but dont have a clue how to do this in code, at moment I have doing it just in excel document.

Answer (score 0):

> but keeps saying it is not a valid DateTime

i think your field in db is DateTime type.this is for what you are doing in your foreach.your are converting it to a 'string' and now you try to save a string .change the db field from DateTime to nchar or nvarchar and store time in string format the way you want.
now every time you get data from db

Comment: I have tried Field in database as dateTime and nvarchar doesnt make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is with this line

```
rw["Scheduled Start as start time"] = rw["Scheduled Start as start time"].ToString("hh-mm");
```

If rw["Scheduled Start as start time"] is a DateTime as I suspect, then you cannot then assign a string to it...its a DateTime, not a string. It must have a full date and time.

You could change the type to be a string and store the datetime elsewhere or store the string elsewhere.

Comment: I dont know what you mean, whatever I store it has DateTime keeps saying is not valid DateTime.  Dont know what im doing wrong.

Answer (score -1):

try this one

String.Format("{0:t}", dt);  // "4:05 PM"                         ShortTime
String.Format("{0:d}", dt);  // "3/9/2008"                        ShortDate